# Renewing, how do I transmit legally with the new certification process (USA)?

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

So, from what I hear, the FCC has done away with mailing out paper certificates.  The way I read the regs, I'm required to have an official paper certificate either on my person or at the station I'm operating.  I know I can print out copies from online, but those are clearly marked as "copy" and are not considered official.

What do I have to do in order to transmit legally once my renewal goes through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which part of the regulations talk about the paper certificate?

I didn't read every word but I searched part 97 for the words paper, person, certificate etc and didn't find any reference to it.

Comment: You are correct.  My copy was out of date.  I found a September 2014 (newer than mine) version which states (in station license section): "The station apparatus must be under the physical control of a person named in an amateur station license grant on the ULS consolidated license database or..."  The control operator section has similar language.  Looks like being named in the ULS is a complete replacement for certificates for legal operation.  Now, proof for tower builds, license plates, etc, that's another thing...  I'd imagine the unofficial copies *should* be accepted though.

Answer (score 4):

You need to register with the [ULS](http://wireless.fcc.gov/uls/index.htm?job=home) (Universal Licensing System) which is part of the FCC's web site.  You can print a copy of your license which states 'official copy'.